# Design Pattern: How to structure the following scenario into proper classes?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

This is more like a code "architecture" question.
I have two classes One and Two. They both need data and styles, so I use two methods getData and getStyles implemented in a parent class.
In the class Two, I perform some extra "transformations" or processing on both data and styles, then return it.

Is this a good approach? Is there a way to make it better? For instance, I am using two same lines getData() and getStyles() in both class One and Two.

```
public abstract class Base {
   protected Data getData() {
       // some code to get data and return it
   }

   protected Styles getStyles() {
       // some code to get styles and return it
   }
}

public class One extends Base {
   public String generateResult() {
       Data data = getData();
       Styles styles = getStyles();
       return getStreamedResult(data, styles);
   }
}

public class Two extends Base {
   public String generateResult() {
       Data data = getData();
       Styles styles = getStyles();
       Transforms transformedResult = performTransform(data, styles);
       return getStreamedResult(transformedResult);
   }
}
```

Comment: If data and style are variables in Base you can make them protected

Comment: I think it looks fine.

Comment: In class `Two` you can move invokations of  `getData()` and `getStyle()` to `performTransform()` and then remove the parameters from `performTransform`. This will look better.

Comment: You may get better answers if you provide the real names of your classes.  What you think is the important information "two classes need... ", etc.   Is not really the important information.  Like what the responsibilities of these classes are, how they are related to the base, and whether or not there is some business rule that says they should use the same data and styles.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```java
public abstract class Base {
   protected Data getData() {
       // some code to get data and return it
   }

   protected Styles getStyles() {
       // some code to get styles and return it
   }

   public String generateResult() {
       Data data = getData();
       Styles styles = getStyles();
       Transforms transformedResult = performTransform(data, styles);
       return getStreamedResult(transformedResult);
   }

   public abstract Transforms performTransform(Data data, Styles styles);
}

public class One extends Base {
   @Override
   public Transforms performTransform(Data data, Styles styles) {
      // unit transform, data and styles are unmodified
   }
}

public class Two extends Base {
   @Override
   public Transforms performTransform(Data data, Styles styles) {
      // intended transforms for class Two
   }
}
```

In each child class, you would have to specify only what the transform is.

Comment: So, the thing is only Class Two uses the transform. There is no need in Class one for the transform.

Comment: Class One having a dummy `performTransform` that isn't needed is certainly a con of the solution I proposed. I actually made the assumption, perhaps incorrectly, that you would need to add more children classes. In that case, I would find more elegant to define in each child class only the transformation by way of redefining `performTransform`, even if this means having a dummy transformation for one child class (only) among several. However, in case you really only need these two child classes, the code I proposed certainly is an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

While keeping the basic tenets of design practices in OOP in mind, this is how i'd write this with what i could understand from your implementation.

```
//created Data and Styles interface for the sake of completion
public interface Data {
}

public interface Styles {
}

//it's always a good practice to code to interfaces, but you 
//may choose to not do this
public interface DataObject {
    public Data getData();

    public Styles getStyles();
}

public class DefaultDataObject implements DataObject {
    private final Data data;
    private final Styles styles;

    public DefaultDataObject(Data data, Styles styles) {
        this.data = data;
        this.styles = styles;
    }

    @Override
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public Styles getStyles() {
        return styles;
    }
}

//i have tried to encapsulate the result generation logic 
//through this interface
public interface Result<T extends DataObject> {
    public String generate(T dataObject);
}

//the normal, streamed result type
public class StreamedResult<T extends DataObject> 
    implements Result<T> {

    @Override
    public String generate(T dataObject) {
        return Results.getStreamedResult(dataObject);
    }
}

//the transformed streamed result type
public class TransformedStreamedResult<T extends DataObject> 
    implements Result<T> {

    @Override
    public String generate(T dataObject) {
        //i have taken an assumption here that transform returns 
        //the same type of object
        transform(dataObject);
        return Results.getStreamedResult(dataObject);
    }

    private void transform(T dataObject) {
        //do transformation here
    }
}

//strategy class defining which result generation logic to 
//be chosen for a particular data object
public static class ResultStrategy {
    private ResultStrategy(){}    

    public static <T extends DataObject> Result<T> 
        getResult(T dataObject) {
        //on the basis of some strategy logic, you can return 
        //a particular implementation of Result here
    }

}

//utility class for Results
public class Results {
    private Results() {
    }

    //if you **MUST** have a different `Transforms` type, 
    //you can overload this method for it.
    public static final <T extends DataObject> String 
        getStreamedResult(T datObject) {
        //do something here and return a string
    }
}
```